# How to strip down comma-separated strings to unique substrings

Tags: r, regex

I'm struggling to strip down comma-separated strings to unique substrings in a cleanly fashion:

```
x <- c("Anna & x, Anna & x", #
       "Alb, Berta 222, Alb", 
       "Al Pacino", 
       "Abb cd xy, Abb cd xy, C123, C123, B")
```

I seem to be doing fine with this combination of negative characterclass, negative lookahead and backreference; however what bothers me is that in many substrings there is unwanted whitespace:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "([^,]+)(?!.*\\1)")
[[1]]
[1] " Anna & x"

[[2]]
[1] " Berta 222" " Alb"      

[[3]]
[1] "Al Pacino"

[[4]]
[1] " Abb cd xy" " C123"      " B"
```

How can the pattern be refined so that no unwanted whitespace gets extracted?

```
Desired result:
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Anna & x"
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Alb"       "Berta 222"
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Al Pacino"
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "Abb cd xy" "C123"      "B"
```

**EDIT**:

Just wanted to share this solution with double negative lookahead, which also works well .

```
str_extract_all(x, "((?!\\s)[^,]+)(?!.*\\1)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start matching from a char other than a whitespace and a comma, then optionally match any zero or more chars other than a comma up to a char other than whitespace and a comma:

```r
str_extract_all(x, "([^\\s,](?:[^,]*[^\\s,])?)(?!.*\\1)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSfppP/1) and an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/47gbop). Mind that if your strings contain line breaks, you need to prepend the pattern with `(?s)`: `str_extract_all(x, "(?s)([^\\s,](?:[^,]*[^\\s,])?)(?!.*\\1)")`.

If you need to make it case insensitive (e.g. `Abb cd xy` and `ABB cD Xy` are considered duplicates), add the `i` flag: `str_extract_all(x, "(?i)([^\\s,](?:[^,]*[^\\s,])?)(?!.*\\1)")` (or `str_extract_all(x, "(?si)([^\\s,](?:[^,]*[^\\s,])?)(?!.*\\1)")` if the DOTALL behavior is needed).

*Details*:

- `([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\s,]` - a char other than whitespace and a comma
  - `(?:[^,]*[^\s,])?` - an optional sequence  of

    - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma
    - `[^\s,]` - a char other than whitespace and a comma
- `(?!.*\1)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars, as many as possible, followed with the Group 1 value.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str_split` to get the individual substrings, followed by `unique` to remove repeated strings. For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

str_split(x, ", ?") %>% map(unique)
```

> [[1]]
> [1] "Anna & x"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "Alb"       "Berta 222"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "Al Pacino"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "Abb cd xy" "C123"      "B"

If you want the output as a single vector of unique strings, you could do:

```r
unique(unlist(str_split(x, ", ?")))
```

> [1] "Anna & x"  "Alb"       "Berta 222" "Al Pacino" "Abb cd xy" "C123" "B"

In the code above we used the regex `", ?"` to split at a comma or a comma followed by a space so that we don't end up with a leading space. For future reference, if you do need to get rid of leading or trailing whitespace, you can use `str_trim`. For example, if we had used `","` in `str_split` we could do the following:

```
str_split(x, ",") %>% 
  map(str_trim) %>% 
  map(unique)
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your pattern to the one below:

```
str_extract_all(x, "(\\b[^,]+)(?!.*\\1)")
[[1]]
[1] "Anna & x"

[[2]]
[1] "Berta 222" "Alb"      

[[3]]
[1] "Al Pacino"

[[4]]
[1] "Abb cd xy" "C123"      "B"
```

Comment: Actually `str_extract_all(x, "([^, ][^,]*)(?!.*\\1)")`is better as it allows for substrings starting with non-letter chars

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann thats what i previously had. Though the notion here is names. So thought to change to `\\b`

Comment: I know you had this previously. This solution is more felxible and therefore to my mind better.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for, but the NLP frameworks can be helpful when the problems get more complex.

```r
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tibble(text = x) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("stringid") %>% 
  unnest_regex(substring, text, pattern = ",", to_lower = FALSE) %>% 
  distinct(stringid, substring = trimws(substring))

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   stringid substring
#      <int> <chr>    
# 1        1 Anna & x 
# 2        2 Alb      
# 3        2 Berta 222
# 4        3 Al Pacino
# 5        4 Abb cd xy
# 6        4 C123     
# 7        4 B
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `lapply(..., str_trim)` to your code:

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(x, "([^,]+)(?!.*\\1)"), str_trim)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "Anna & x"

[[2]]
[1] "Berta 222" "Alb"      

[[3]]
[1] "Al Pacino"

[[4]]
[1] "Abb cd xy" "C123"      "B"
```